# How to transform single column data into multiple column multiple row in r

Tags: r, conditional-statements, dplyr, dcast

I am trying to transform this data frame:

```
   YID     UID     N    Beaufort
   BC01   43696    3       3
   BC01   43993    4       1
   BC01   44015    6       1
   BC02   44000    2       1
   BC02   44012    1       1
   BC03   43986    2       2
   BC03   44013    3       3
```

into

```
    YID  V1  V2  V3  V4  B1  B2  B3  B4
    BC01  3   4   6   NA  3   1   1   NA 
    BC02  2   1   NA  NA  1   1   NA  NA
    BC03  2   3   NA  NA  2   3   NA  NA
```

YID are sites and Vs and Bs are visit-specific.

I tried to use

```
dcast(setDT(SOSA2), YID~n, value.var=c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4))
```

I also tried mutuate in dplyr and spread but not sure the best way to go about this one. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  select(-UID) %>%
  group_by(YID) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = c(N, Beaufort))

#   YID     N_1   N_2   N_3 Beaufort_1 Beaufort_2 Beaufort_3
#  <chr> <int> <int> <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1 BC01      3     4     6          3          1          1
#2 BC02      2     1    NA          1          1         NA
#3 BC03      2     3    NA          2          3         NA
```

Comment: Thank you this was a big help! For anyone else interested, the function pivot_wider() is not in the newest version of tidyr and I had to bring it into r using "install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/tidyr")"